# Running total for SQL column that is part of subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, cumulative-sum

Lots of posts here describe how to do running totals, but I'm faced with a situation where the running total needs to be that of a column that's calculated using a sub-query (which means my current ORDER BY causes the query to fail)

I have a table that show amounts per time period, something like this:

```
TimePeriod   Amount
2022-03-31   396
2022-03-31   16
2022-03-31   84
2021-12-31   842
2021-12-31   57
2021-09-30   652
2021-09-30   25
2021-09-30   173
```

In my query, I need to find the percentage of the total for each time period. What I've done is this:

```
SELECT 
    TimePeriod,
    SUM(Amount) AS 'Total Per Period', 
    CAST( ROUND( SUM(Amount)/(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM MyDatabase.MyTable),3) AS DECIMAL(12,3)) AS 'Percentage of Total'
FROM
    MyDatabase.MyTable
GROUP BY
    TimePeriod
ORDER BY
    TimePeriod DESC
```

This gives me a correct output, like so:

```
TimePeriod   Total per Period   Percentage of total
2022-03-31   496                0.221
2021-12-31   899                0.400
2021-09-30   850                0.379
```

What I want to do is add a running total of the 'Percentage of total' column, something like:

```
TimePeriod   Total per Period   Percentage of total   Running total percentage
2022-03-31   496                0.221                 0.221
2021-12-31   899                0.400                 0.621
2021-09-30   850                0.379                 1.000
```

What I tried to do was first just add it in the first SELECT clause but that doesn't work since it's a column that only exists in my query. I then tried to do a select of that select, like so:

```
SELECT
    TimePeriod,
    'Total Per Period',
    'Percentage of Total',
    SUM('Percentage of Total') OVER (ORDER BY TimePeriod)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        TimePeriod,
        SUM(Amount) AS 'Total Per Period', 
        CAST( ROUND( SUM(Amount)/(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM MyDatabase.MyTable),3) AS DECIMAL(12,3)) AS 'Percentage of Total'
    FROM
        MyDatabase.MyTable
    GROUP BY
        TimePeriod
    ORDER BY
        TimePeriod DESC)
```

This throws the error saying that the last ORDER BY is not allowed in sub-queries. Removing ORDER BY instead says that the syntax is incorrect. I'm guessing that the problem is that I have a subquery referencing a subquery result, but I'm not sure how to work around this one. What seems to be missing from my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some syntax errors, as well as some improvements to make:

- As mentioned in the other answer, the derived table needs an alias
- Use `[]` to quote column names if necessary (preferably don't have such column names in the first place).
- You cannot have `ORDER BY` inside a derived table or subquery, nor does it make sense to do so.
- You can replace the `SELECT SUM` subquery with `SUM(SUM) OVER ()` window function.
- The running total window function must have `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` if `TimePeriod` may have duplicates. It's also faster.
- Because you are ordering by `TimePeriod DESC`, it may be faster to do the running total in the same order as the main `ORDER BY` but with `ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` which works out to the same results. The benefit is one less sort in the query plan.

```sql
SELECT
    TimePeriod,
    [Total Per Period],
    [Percentage of Total],
    SUM([Percentage of Total]) OVER (ORDER BY TimePeriod DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        TimePeriod,
        SUM(Amount) AS [Total Per Period],
        CAST( ROUND( SUM(Amount) / SUM(SUM(Amount)) OVER () , 3) AS DECIMAL(12,3)) AS [Percentage of Total]
    FROM
        MyDatabase.MyTable
    GROUP BY
        TimePeriod
) t
ORDER BY
    TimePeriod DESC;
```

A further improvement would be to combine the whole thing into one level:

```sql
SELECT
    TimePeriod,
    SUM(Amount) AS [Total Per Period],
    CAST( ROUND(
            SUM(Amount) /
            SUM(SUM(Amount)) OVER ()
          , 3) AS DECIMAL(12,3)) AS [Percentage of Total],
    CAST( ROUND(
            SUM(SUM(Amount)) OVER (ORDER BY TimePeriod DESC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) /
            SUM(SUM(Amount)) OVER ()
          , 3) AS DECIMAL(12,3))
FROM
    MyDatabase.MyTable
GROUP BY
    TimePeriod
ORDER BY
    TimePeriod DESC;
```

Note that the results may be slightly different due to rounding.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2e3d22/3)

Comment: Wow, yeah this is much more concise, thank you! Lots of new concepts for me here :) TimePeriod very much have duplicates as there are other columns I omitted here for the sake of the question (one row per product for each TimePeriod), the only one I don't really grasp right now is the ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING, so I'll take a look at that. Much to learn still, thanks a lot!

Comment: Basically that part is the *window frame* which could cover the whole thing (as in `OVER ()`) or it could look back at previous rows (your original). This version looks forwards. In order to get the same results, you flip the ordering to `DESC`, this has the benefit of being able to use the same sort as the main `ORDER BY`

Comment: Thanks! I tried with both DESC and ASC in the OVER(ORDER BY...) clause and I kinda get it, but one last question then: when I change from UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING to PRECEDING I get an error, wouldn't DESC using UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING be the same as ASC using UNBOUNDED PRECEDING?

Comment: Yes correct, it is the same. Either `ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` or `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` (the latter *only* can be shortened to `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`)

Comment: aaaaah, so if I use preceding I need to use it before the current row! That was what was missing, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You might need to use `[]` to contain column name instead of `'` which means string value, also we need to give subquery an alias name.

```
SELECT
    TimePeriod,
    [Total Per Period],
    [Percentage of Total],
    SUM([Percentage of Total]) OVER (ORDER BY TimePeriod)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        TimePeriod,
        SUM(Amount) AS 'Total Per Period', 
        CAST( ROUND( SUM(Amount)/(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM MyDatabase.MyTable),3) AS DECIMAL(12,3)) AS 'Percentage of Total'
    FROM
        MyDatabase.MyTable
    GROUP BY
        TimePeriod) t1
ORDER BY
    TimePeriod DESC
```

Comment: Oh man, this worked wonders! Thank you! And of course, the ORDER BY needs to be outside so I'm sorting the final query. I was staring myself blind on this for too long haha :)  EDIT: For future readers I also verified that it wasn't one or the other but both using [] and naming the subquery that was required for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to your problem. I solve it in Oracle.

```
with flo as (
    select
      timeperiod, 
      sum(amount) as amount,
      cast((sum(amount) / (select sum(amount) from da ))as decimal(10,6)) *100.0 as percent_of_total
    from  yourtable
    group by timeperiod
)
select
  timeperiod,
  amount,
  percent_of_total,
  sum(percent_of_total) over (order by timeperiod desc ) as running
from flo;
```